# Signals don't get emitted

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I have a simple class **Networking** with a:

```
private:
    QNetworkAccessManager *httpclient;
```

I create an object in the constructor and connect signal and slot:

```
 httpclient = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
 connect(httpclient, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(httpRequestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

Now I am going to call the QNetworkAccessManager's get method via a public method getPage:

```
void Networking::getPage(const QString &uri)
{
  QNetworkRequest request;
  request.setUrl(uri);
  httpclient->get(request);
}
```

I expect that **httpRequestFinished** gets called, but it's not.
I also tried it this for testing purposes:

```
void Networking::getPage(const QString &uri)
{
  QNetworkRequest request;
  request.setUrl(uri);
  reply = httpclient->get(request);
  connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(httpReplyFinished()));
}
```

where **reply** is properly defined in file **networking.h**:

```
private:
 QNetworkAccessManager *httpclient;
 QNetworkReply *reply;
```

Nothing changed! But if I access **reply->bytesAvailable()** after the get-Request all signals are emitted at the same time! I'm searching now for hours but don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

so... i found out why - but not exactly: it was memory management.
I had to define my object as pointer in my mainwindow class

```
Networking *nw;
```

Now i can use it - for example in my pushbutton-action:

```
nw = new Networking();
nw->getPage("my url here");
```

All went as expected!
Ufff.. Much to learn